# Exporting Adobe Tracker data / obtaining Tracker RSS feed

Tags: javascript, rss, adobe, acrobat, tracker

I'm attempting to "extract" any data from Adobe tracker. For example, number of comments, reviewer name. I can't find any way to do this so far. I know that Tracker just uses RSS feeds but I can't find WHERE exactly all of this is located and where to pull it from. Has anyone ever done this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it. It's pretty straightforward. The repository where you are collecting the comments will have a bunch of XML files. There'll be a folder for each document at the root of the repository and then an XML (RSS) file for each user in each document folder. Each comment by that user is an "item" in the RSS. There are a bunch of other details about the comment as well and there are extensions to RSS that Adobe uses. Those are in the documentation at the link below.

Tracker Documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/Acro12_MasterBook/Tracker_Introduction/About_Acrobat_Tracker.htm

Comment: The comment repository though is just that, only for comments. What about reviewers that haven't left comments yet?

Comment: To clarify, only reviewers/people that have opened the pdf/have left a comment have a .xml file in the comment repository.

Comment: Acrobat can upload the review file to the repository but it's not required. The  design intent was to allow users to distribute the document in whatever fashion they liked (since graphically intensive PDF can be HUGE!) and the comments would be these lightweight RSS files. A user gets an invitation to review a document with a link or an attachment and only the RSS moves over the wire while they are reviewing. The XML file is created by the end user's copy of Acrobat or Reader so only actual participants have an XML file.

Comment: That said, the Tracker is customizable so one *could* collect the addresses of all of the invitees at the point of initiating the review and then diff that list with the existence of a corresponding XML file to determine those who have not commented.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! So you mean customizing Tracker so that it keeps a list of all reviewers, then I would compare the two lists (one being the XML files) to see who hasn't commented.

Comment: Yes - Though, I now don't think you need to customize the Tracker. The list of reviewers is stored in a bit of JavaScript that loads when the document is opened. Tracker is able to read this. The methods to do so are in the Collab object but are undocumented. When you initiate the review, Acrobat will create a folder in the repository that is named as follows. The file name followed by two underscores and then the review ID. Use the review ID in the following JavaScript to get the list of reviewers. Collab.getReviewInfo("REVIEWID").cRequiredReviewers; There's also cOptionalReviewers.

Comment: Glad it's working. How do I know this? That's a long story but the short version is I've been working with Acrobat since 1993. I'm the former Technical Evangelist for Acrobat at Adobe and I kind of invented the predecessor to Shared Reviews.

Comment: I also just enumerated the methods of the Collab object and poked at it with a stick until I figured out what does what. While the necessary methods are undocumented, they *are* enumerable.